# How to change the position of response.write();

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, responsive-design

So this is the view :

```
    @model CMSFC.Models.Page
    @{    
       Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
     }

    @{
       Response.Write(Model.Template);
     }
```

It renders a html table (saved in Template column) from database , with header footer body and so on .. But this renders a very small table on the top left corner of the application , i want to render that html table on the entire screen of view .

Comment: You should try the HTML and css to re-position your table or data.

Comment: Can you help me with that ?!

Comment: You should probably revisit the very basics of web development. After that you should think about why you are storing complete html tables in a database.